# Javascript move DIV with inertia

Tags: javascript

I have a code where I can move an object by mouse:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #container {
        position:absolute;
        width: 60px;
        height: 40px;
        top:50px;
        left:50px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        mydragg = function(){
                return {
                    startMoving : function(divid, evt) {
                        evt = evt || window.event;
                        var diffX = evt.clientX - divid.offsetLeft,
                            diffY = evt.clientY - divid.offsetTop;

                        document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
                            evt = evt || window.event;
                            divid.style.left = evt.clientX - diffX + 'px';
                            divid.style.top  = evt.clientY - diffY + 'px';
                        }
                    },
                    stopMoving : function() {
                        document.onmousemove = null;
                    },
                }
        }();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container' onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this, event);' onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving();'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works, but I need more - inertia - when I do "mouseup" DIV must continue to move a little, according to the previous movement's speed. An example could be Google Maps - you move a map with inertia.

I need the same with pure JavaScript functions (no jQuery, no interact.js or something 3'rd partly like that).

If you can - you can modify the code to use "transform" instead of "style.left/top", because performance and looking good is the most important thing.

Can you help to add inertia's code?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I've tried to calculate dX and dY (something we can call speed) and then in a loop to change DIV's position by dY/dX (and decreasing dX/dY until "1" or "0") - but it looks horrible and I'm sure it is wrong

Comment: Your idea is basically correct. I followed an article [by Ariya Hidayat](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/08/javascript-kinetic-scrolling-part-1.html) to implement something similar.

Comment: It's just a matter of mass, velocity and retarding-force (friction).Wiki will have the relevant equations, which I've long ago forgotten.

Comment: @MikeC, I've tried to implement inertia from scrolling script.. unfortunately it works too slow. There are too many calculations all the time while a mouse is down, and every 100ms many global variables are recalculated. I need something more lightweight